# Writing unit test cases for Sitecore project

Tags: sitecore, moq, sitecore8, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper

My client wants to have 100% code coverage for all the projects. I have written few test cases very long back for Web API's using nUnit. But my client decided to use xUnit as a unit test framework using Moq as Mock framework.

As i have never worked on unit test case for sitecore project, could anyone please en-light us on the approach? As a start coudl anyone please write a sample test case for the below method? We are using GlassMapperFramework as a ORM.

```
public class RegistrationController : GlassController
    {
    public ActionResult RegistrationInitiation()
            {
                var someobject = GetDataSourceItem<IRegistrationMainContent>();

                return View(someobject);
            }
}
```

Comment: Online search found this [Unit testing Sitecore MVC](https://mhwelander.net/2014/04/30/unit-testing-sitecore-mvc/)

Comment: Online Search found this [Life Through a Lens – Unit Testing with Glass Controllers](https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2015/09/29/life-through-a-lens-unit-testing-with-glass-controllers/)

Comment: Yeah, tried few things but im facing issue while intializing controller constructor. The exception is something like, GlassController dependancy not met.

Answer (score 1):

To test your Controllers, you will want to inject the Sitecore Context into the Controller. The GlassController has an overload method on it GlassController(ISitecoreContext). This is used to Unit Test your controllers. It also has other overloads if needed...

Here is more complete code you need to unit test the controller

```cs
private Mock<IRegistrationModel> RegistrationModel { get; set; };
private RegistrationController Controller { get; set; }

[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    var mockSitecoreContext = new Mock<ISitecoreContext>();
    this.RegistrationModel = new Mock<IRegistrationModel>();

    this.RegistrationModel.SetupAllProperties();

    mockSitecoreContext.Setup(sc =>sc.GetItem<IRegistrationModel
        (It.IsAny<string>(), false, false)).
        Returns(this.RegistrationModel.Object);

    this.Controller = new RegistrationController {SitecoreContext =
        mockSitecoreContext.Object }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Your_Unit_Test_Name()
{
    //....perform unit test here
    this.Controller.SitecoreContext = null;

    var result = this.Controller.GetIndex() as ViewResult;

    //Assert ....
}
```

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: In the above code, the Registrationcontroller is invoked with no argument. Which is giving compile time error.
I have tried
  controller = new RegistrationController(sitecoreContextMock.Object). But it did' worked as it was not resolving the dependency for the GlassController. 
Things to mention here is, i'm using GlassController, not the mvc controller. Any idea?

Comment: PaRsH, I apologize for the delayed response. I modified the code above. The code above should give you more insight in unit testing with the GlassController if you are inheriting from it. If you are not, you should be able to replace RegistratioController with GlassController.